# How to organize javascript on the front-end w/o using server technologies?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a front-end javascript project with the follow characteristics:

1. Performance does not matter
2. Lots of classes
3. Client only.

The third point is my main reason for asking this question as when I research how to organize javascript on the client side the answers usually include some server-side library. I do NOT have access to this. I would like to keep my classes in one folder (maybe some sub-folders), a main script, and another folder with 3rd party libraries. I haven't found a way of doing this nicely however.

I've tried in my one html file to do this:

```
<!-- include 3rd party librayA -->
<!-- include 3rd party librayB -->
<!-- include classA script -->
<!-- include classB script -->
<!-- include main.js -->
```

But the main.js didn't seem to know what the classes were.

Ideally I'd like something like require but, again anything I've found similar to that uses a server side tech which I can't use.

Here is what a reduced form of what I tried:

./index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="test/javascript" src="./classes/TestClass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

./script.js

```
var testClassInstance = new TestClass("test!");
testClassInstance.bar();
```

./Classes/TestClass.js

```
var TestClass = function (foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
};

TestClass.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log(this.foo);
}
```

The error I got was:

```
script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: TestClass is not defined(…)
```

Comment: If you want to easily do this, I recommend looking in to [Require JS](http://requirejs.org/). It can take care of loading the files needed for a give page as well as do the dependency management. No server side tech needed to get it working. I will add though that despite the fact that you might see "server side" solutions like a Webpack server with gulp and browserify and whatever other library is popular right now, you can use those for development only and then get them to output a bundled static version of your front end JS dependencies.

Comment: Also to help answer the problem you're seeing here, can you give a reduced set of code that produces the problem where `main.js` doesn't know what the classes are? It could depend on the structure of your code inside the individual files.

Comment: @Dymos edited with the structure. TBH I'm not sure if there is an error on my part or if my approach is just that wrong. Thanks!

Comment: "testClass is not defined(…)" `testClass` is lowercase there, worth checking you're using the right case when referencing the `TestClass`

Comment: @Dymos whoops sorry I caught that I redid the "test" and still got the same results but forgot to update the error.

Comment: haha no worries. What you have there looks like it should absolutely work, It's definitely loading both/all the JS files? Check out the network tab in developer tools in Firefox or Chrome while you reload the page and see if there are any files that don't load.

Comment: @Dymos it is all loading.

Comment: ok well definitely looks like it should work ok. Could be worth verifying that it works the same in other browsers. Having said that, give Require JS a try and see if that helps out as well, given that it will likely help out with managing the dependencies as well, it ought to make your life a little easier anyway :)

Comment: @Dymos type="test/javascript" shoulda been type="text/javascript".... Thanks though! will check out require might be a little much for this project though.

Comment: oh snap, I guess browsers still read that attribute :P - FWIW you can leave off the `type` attribute on script tags for JavaScript, it isn't really necessary :)